# PrimeNG 10.0.3 - error NG8001: 'p-tabView' is not a known element

Tags: primeng

I am using PrimeNG 10.0.3 in an angular 10 application.  In it I am importing several PrimeNG components and using them without an issue.  However, when I try to use the TabView module, I get **error NG8001: 'p-tabView' is not a known element** as well as **error NG8001: 'p-tabPanel' is not a known element**.

I have created a module called primng.module where I host all the PrimeNG imports:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { BlockUIModule } from 'primeng/blockui';
import { ToastModule } from 'primeng/toast';
import { DialogModule } from 'primeng/dialog';
import { ConfirmDialogModule } from 'primeng/confirmdialog';
import { OverlayPanelModule } from 'primeng/overlaypanel';
import { PanelModule } from 'primeng/panel';
import { CardModule } from 'primeng/card';
import { SidebarModule } from 'primeng/sidebar';
import { InputMaskModule } from 'primeng/inputmask';
import { PasswordModule } from 'primeng/password';
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
import { TabViewModule } from 'primeng/tabview';

import { ConfirmationService, MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

@NgModule({
  imports: [

  ],
  exports: [
    ButtonModule,
    BlockUIModule,
    ToastModule,
    DialogModule,
    ConfirmDialogModule,
    OverlayPanelModule,
    PanelModule,
    CardModule,
    SidebarModule,
    InputMaskModule,
    PasswordModule,
    TableModule,
    TabViewModule
  ],
  providers: [
    MessageService,
    ConfirmationService
  ]
})
export class PrimengModule { }
```

Then I import this module as:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { PrimengModule } from '../../primeng.module';

...

const routes: Routes = [
  ...
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    PrimengModule
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

And finally, I am using the TabView as:

```html
  <p-tabView>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header 1">
      Content 1
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header 2">
      Content 2
    </p-tabPanel>
    <p-tabPanel header="Header 3">
      Content 3
    </p-tabPanel>
  </p-tabView>
```

I do not have trouble using any of the other modules, just TabView.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the problem with PrimeNG 10.0.0?

Comment: Yes, I just tried the last version in case the issue was fixed

Comment: @Antikhippe  I even tried 9.1.3 with the same result.

Comment: I also tried clearing my solution by removing my node_modules and package-lock.json, just in case I had some residual conflict, but with no success.

Comment: I don't know, I made it work with PrimeNG 10.0.3: [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabview-demo-uy4mww?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: Yeah,  I see the demo working.  I am just wondering why all the other components are working and only the TabView is failing.  Very strange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out this had nothing to do with PrimeNG.  The hosting component where I had the p-tabView markup was declared, by mistake, in a different module that knew nothing about my primeng.module.ts and naturally did not know how to handle the TabView.

Lesson learned: Be careful which module you declare each component in.  Make sure the module knows about the features you need to use in the component.

Comment: Great suggestion. In my case, the error "[...] is not a known element" was actually a misleading error. The element was known for the bootstraping module (e.g. the PrimeNG module correctly declared in app.module.ts), but the *child component* that was using the PrimeNG module *was not defined in declarations*. Silly mistake, but misleading error

Answer (score 0):

Hey I got similar error when I was using primeng TabMenuModule so it was just the module problem i was importing it in the wrong module as my component was declared in app module but i was importing TabMenuModule in another module as i was thinking it was associated to that.so it was nothing to do with primeng.